# Oracle REST Data Service (ORDS) equivalent in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, oracle

I've started using Oracle REST Data Services (ORDS) for a few projects. This is a middleware tier java app that simply allows access to Oracle Database objects via REST. The objects you can "restify" are things like tables, packages, procedures, views, etc. I'm curious if there is an equivalent native (or first party) feature in Microsoft SQL Server?

Thanks.

Comment: happy to hear you like using ORDS for your oracle projects :)

Comment: The closest is probably [OData](https://www.odata.org/) - but that's a programming construct, not available directly within SQL Server